# I can't make my elif statement work after using input

Tags: python

So I'm making a quick text based application and made a guess at doing this. I want my program to accept an input from the user and create different outcomes when a user inputs a direction. It just is going to the if no matter what I type. I took a shot in the dark and this is my code.

```
print ("Would you like to go left or right?")
input()
if ("left"):
    print ("Welcome to the cleanliness room *squeak!*.")
    print ("Would you like to go forward,or backwards?")
elif ("right"):
    print ("Inhale my dong enragement child.")
    print ("GAME OVER")
```

Comment: That... isn't really code. I mean it runs without error, but it doesn't make *any sense at all*. You don't actually assign the user's input, so you can never refer to it again, and `if "left":` (the parentheses are redundant) is really just `if "left" != "":` or `if True:`, and **doesn't relate at all to the `input`**, so you can hopefully see why you never hit the `elif` case. Maybe take a tutorial?

Comment: Oh, and if you *"made a guess"* or *"took a shot in the dark"*, that **isn't really programming**; read https://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/coincidence

Answer (score 3):

`input()` *returns* a result, but you ignored it and nothing happened with it. `if ("left"):` just asks if the string `"left"` is not empty. It is indeed not empty.

Store the return value of `input()` in a new variable, then test that variable for equality with `==`:

```
print ("Would you like to go left or right?")
answer = input()
if answer == "left":
    print("Welcome to the cleanliness room *squeak!*.")
    print("Would you like to go forward,or backwards?")
elif answer == "right":
    print("Inhale my dong enragement child.")
    print("GAME OVER")
```

You probably want to peruse the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) some more.